# I have a SSRS calculation but i do not know how to get it to work in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

the equation  TotalDebits = result.CreditsAndDeposits + result.Refund - result.RentTax - result.SalesTax - result.Insurance

How can I get the calculation in SSRS?
[image: Receipts]
My data table results
Any ideas would be great.

[image: Table structure]

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the value of the textbox to do your equation.

`TotalDebits = ReportItems!CreditsAndDeposits.Value + ReportItems!Refund.Value - ReportItems!RentTax.Value - ReportItems!SalesTax.Value - ReportItems!Insurance.Value`

I'm guessing at the names of the textboxes. I'd maybe prefix the textbox names with "DT" or "MTD", etc to reference the column it's in.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-reportitems-collection-references-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I will give you screen shot of my structure of my table

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by puting in a expression.
=SUM(IIF(Fields!strType.Value="CreditsAndDeposits",CInt(Fields!intDT.Value),CInt(0)))

### +
SUM(IIF(Fields!strType.Value="Refunds", CInt(Fields!intDT.Value),CInt(0)))

SUM(IIF(Fields!strType.Value="Rent Tax",CInt(Fields!intDT.Value),CInt(0)))

-
SUM(IIF(Fields!strType.Value="Sales Tax",CInt(Fields!intDT.Value),CInt(0)))

-
SUM(IIF(Fields!strType.Value="Cost of Insurance",CInt(Fields!intDT.Value),
CInt(0)))